make4ht mathML not converting \left\llbracket properly
Minimal working example:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}
This works:
\[
    \llbracket \frac{\pi}{2} \rrbracket
\]

This doesn't:
\[
    \left\llbracket \frac{\pi}{2} \right\rrbracket
\]
\end{document}

When compiling with pdftex I get the correct output:

When instead compiling this with make4ht test "mathml", I instead get:

Why doesn't make4ht/mathml not like the \left and \right commands in combination with \llbracket?

There is no support for the stmaryrd package in TeX4ht yet. I've added it to TeX4ht sources. Until you get the update, you can use this config file:
\Preamble{xhtml}

\catcode`\:=11
\Configure{left}
   {}
   {\HCode{<\a:mathml mrow><\a:mathml mo \a:mathml fence="true" \a:mathml form="prefix">%
       \expandafter
\ifx \csname \string#1:lr del\endcsname\relax #1\else
     \csname \string#1:lr del\endcsname\fi
</\a:mathml mo>}\bgroup
                              \HCode{<\a:mathml mrow>}\bgroup}
\catcode`\:=12
\Configure{mfenced}{\llbracket}{\string&\#x27E6;}
\Configure{mfenced}{\rrbracket}{\string&\#x27E7;}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble

The \Configure{left} is required to remove a spurious space which TeX4ht generates after \left, and which can cause a wrong rendering of brackets.


Thanks! And to be clear: this would have to be passed as a config file for make4ht as an additional commandline argument?

@John, yes something like $ make4ht -c config.cfg test.tex "mathml"

Hmm, this is weird, but when I use your config it is scaling correctly the right bracket, but the left bracket stays at the small size. It generated this mathML, which does look correct: <mo fence='true' form='prefix'> ⟦</mo><mrow><mfrac><mrow><mi>π</mi></mrow> <mrow><mn>2</mn></mrow></mfrac> </mrow><mo fence='true' form='postfix'>⟧</mo>

@John it looks fine in Firefox, but in the way as you said with Chromium. It is even worse if I add MathJax. It italicizes the non-fenced version, and makes the fenced brackets really small. I guess that these are errors in renderers, maybe because these characters are not that common? The MathML code looks fine and looks fine in brower if you replace the double brackets with parens, for example.

@John I've found the issue. There is an extra space before the left bracket, this causes the rendering in Chromium to fail.

@michal.h21 unfortunately mathml-core dropped the stripping of white space in token elements such as mo so it's no longer true that <mo> ( </mo>  is the same as <mo>(</mo>

@DavidCarlisle thanks for the info. It wasn't intentional space, it was cause by a forgotten % at the end of line. Of course :D
